# Why is Service Networking not getting routed by VPC Network Peering?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a default network:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  description = "Default network for the project"
  name = "default"
}
```

Inside that network I have many subnets and a Serverless VPC connector. I also have a Service Networking address so that Cloud SQL can connect to my VPC:

```
# private VPC IP address for the SQL DB.
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider = google-beta

  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 24
  address       = "10.0.2.0"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id
}
```

I have a staging VPC in another GCP project so I configured VPC Network Peering. Everything is "routed" (I don't know if that is the correct term, but all other IPs are visible from my other VPN). The problem is my Service Networking address (10.0.2.0) is not visible. I guess it might have to do with the fact that the Service Networking is also a peering connection on its own, but it's all guesswork. Why is that IP not being "routed"?

Comment: Why are you creating a **resource** for a Cloud SQL private IP address?

Comment: @JohnHanley I just followed the instructions in the Terraform documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance

Comment: Your comment above that resource made me believe you were trying to assign that address to Cloud SQL. Edit your question and include the entire HCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up VPC connectors to Cloud SQL, it's using network peering behind the scenes, and because GCP does not support transitive peering - you cannot access it using two VPCs:

> Only directly peered networks can communicate. Transitive peering
> isn't supported. In other words, if VPC network N1 is peered with N2
> and N3, but N2 and N3 aren't directly connected, VPC network N2 can't
> communicate with VPC network N3 over VPC Network Peering. Clients in
> one project can connect to Cloud SQL instances in multiple projects
> using Shared VPC networks.

From the "Transitive peering" Topic in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#quick-reference).

I do not recall if Cloud SQL supports multiple VPC connectors, but another way to solve it is to use shared VPC if you don't have any restrictions.